# How to use /dev/sdb with DRBD?

Tags: centos, mount, drbd

Setting-up `DRBD` on CentOS 7 now.

The configuration is:

```
resource testdata1 {
    protocol C;
    on node1 {
            device /dev/drbd0;
            disk /dev/sdb;
            address 198.19.0.1:7788;
            meta-disk internal;
    }
    on node2 {
            device /dev/drbd0;
            disk /dev/sdb;
            address 198.10.0.2:7788;
            meta-disk internal;
    }
}
```

I have create the path with:

```
# mkdir -p /dev/sdb
```

When I run the initialize meta data command:

```
# drbdadm create-md testdata1
```

Got this message:

```
open(/dev/sdb) failed: Is a directory
open(/dev/sdb) failed: Is a directory
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/sdb internal create-md' terminated with exit code 20
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `/dev/sdb` is a directory and isn't device. `sda` means scsi disk `a`, sdb - scsi disk `b` and etc. There are devices block special files for input and output operations witch are created by system automatically. You must have real hard disk or partition on it to create DRBD device.

Comment: `/dev/sdb` should not be a directory, it should be a block special file.

Comment: @heemayl Thanks. I have corrected terminology.